# What does this code in .cicleci/config.yml mean?

Tags: flask, circleci, flake8, circleci-2.0

My coworkers are trying to write unit test code and test API by using Circleci2.0 and Flake8. But I don't understand how I should write test code because this line `pytest --flake8` in the below code does not mean.

What does this code in .cicleci/config.yml mean ?

Do we need to write test code in another xx.py file and execute this .py file like `pytest xx.py`?

If we should, does this line `pytest --flake8` mean execution of xx.py file in another directly or the same directly even though this code dose not mention file path which execute test code file ?

```
  - run:
          name: Flake8 Check
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            pytest --flake8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify a filename. To quote the Pytest docs:

> By default, `pytest` will run all files of the form `test_*.py` or `*_test.py` in the current directory and its subdirectories. More generally, it follows [standard test discovery rules](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery).